# CMake failing to build nested subdirectories

Tags: c, cmake, esp-idf

Take the following fairly standard looking directory structure for a firmware project (an ESP32 project):

### Folder Struct

```
- myProject/
         - CMakeLists.txt
         - sdkconfig
         - components/ - component1/ - CMakeLists.txt
         
                                     - component1a/ - CMakeLists.txt
                                                    - src/monkey_test.c
                                                    - include/monkey_test.h
                                                    
                                     - component1b/ - CMakeLists.txt
                                                    - src/src1b.c
                                                    - include/src1b.h
                                                    
                       - component2/ - CMakeLists.txt
                                     - src/src2.c
                                     - include/ - src2.h
                                     
         - main/       - src/app_main.c
                       - src/other_stuff.c

         - build/
```

Now let's start with the simplest thing possible. If I create monkey_test.h & .h as:

### Source

```
#include <monkey_test.h>

int monkey_test(void) {
    return 1;
}
```

### Include

```
#ifndef MONKEY_WIFI_H__
#define MONKEY_WIFI_H__

int monkey_test(void);

#endif
```

### Main

```
#include <monkey_test.h>
main() {
  
    sprintf("test value %s", monkey_test());
    
}
```

### CMake Files

**Top Level CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/components)
list(APPEND EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../common)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(proj_name)
```

**component1 CMakeLists.txt**

```
list(APPEND EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/component1a)
```

**Component CMakeLists.txt (for all components)**

```
idf_component_register(  
    SRC_DIRS     "src"     
    INCLUDE_DIRS "include" 
)
```

When I build this, it doesn't work.

../main/src/app_main.c:54:10: fatal error: monkey_test.h: No such file or directory
#include <monkey_test.h>

### Things I've tried

I tried rewriting the component1 CMakeLists.txt as `include(wifi/CMakeLists.txt)` and `idf_build_process(wifi)`. Neither work, and I don't really know why I thought it might.

Also, I've tried just removing the component CMakLists.txt and replacing the component1 CMakeLists.txt to directly bring in the component there but even that didn't work???

```
idf_component_register(  
     SRC_DIRS  "component1a/src"            
     INCLUDE_DIRS "component1a/include"     
)
```

I'm sure it's staring me in the face, and I'm being very blind indeed, but anyone know what I'm doing wring here?

Comment: "_`include(wifi/CMakeLists.txt)`_" CMakeLists.txt files are generally for `add_subdirectory`-ing (mostly convention). things that are meant for `include` are generally named with `.cmake` file extension (also convention)

Comment: where is your call to `target_include_directories`? You're getting an include error and you seem to have not ever specified the include directory you want/need.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the prescribed instructions in the ESP-IDF developer's guide as best I can. The honest response to your question is : I don't know. Is my CMake code wrong?

Comment: actually what you're doing may be fine. But I'd not know because I can't see into `idf_component_register`... nvm I can: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/e5926d1b1bc4b9f628499757d68574110b477529/tools/cmake/component.cmake#L409 hm. they call `include_directories` in there...

Comment: how are you making your subdirectories' CMakeLists.txt files part of the project? As I said, you should be including them using [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html).

Comment: The project layout you've shown in your question is not a [mre]. Please create the smallest setup that reproduces the problem.

Comment: component1 CMakeLists.txt was my attempt to make the subdirectory part of the project.- On your advice tried: add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../component1a) and also add_subdirectory(./component1a) Same error. Am I understanding your advice correctly? What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: what file did you put that in?

Comment: In component1 folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really as of the time of this answer.

The problem is the following:

The idea of the idf superset of CMake commands (e.g. all commands prefixed with idf*, such as for example `idf_components_register`) is to automatically resolve dependencies across a multitude of components that change rapidly. So what the authors did was to have a script walk through all folders in components and `EXTRA_COMPONENTS_DIR` and pick up any component that *registers* itself as an idf component and remember its dependencies. The project will then automatically create CMake targets and link each dependent component against each other.

So what if you just include the subcomponenent into the generator tree using add_subdirectory? You can do that, but only AFTER script mode has processed idf_component_register, if you put the command before CMake will complain that `add_subdirectory` is not a scriptable command. And if you put it after, the subcomponents will not be taken up in the dependency graph as the script completes after executing `idf_components_register`, so it will not build.

You could manually add CMakeTargets for each individual subcomponent, and link it back to the root component such as done by [esp_mbedls](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/47253a827a80cb78f22db8e4736c668804c16750/components/mbedtls/CMakeLists.txt#L59). If you include components from external repos this is the way to go, but it only works if your subcomponent doesn't depend on other esp_idf components, as the link targets won't be added automatically for manual components (as the aforementioned script has already been executed by that time).

I hope espressif will add support for nested components in the future, until then we're stuck with the solution that are provided to us unfortunately.

The way I handle it right now is to just have one metacomponent that "manages" the subcomponent, i.e. it adds headers and sources of each subcomponent into its own sources and includes.